# Pass GList by reference

Tags: c, linked-list, glib

I'm attempting to maintain a register of entities as a linked list, with a suite of functions that accept references to the list and modify it in place. I've utilized this tactic with GLists inside of structs to excellent effect, but for this I don't need a container structure. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
// Creates a new entity and appends it to the global entity index.
// Returns ID of the newly created entity, not a pointer to it.
int anne_entity_create(char entity_name[], char entity_type[], GList *Entities) {

    ANNE_ENTITY *newEntity = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_ENTITY));
    ANNE_ENTITY_RECORD *newEntityRecord = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_ENTITY_RECORD));

    newEntity->id = anne_entity_get_next_id(Entities);
    sprintf(newEntity->name, "%s", entity_name);
    sprintf(newEntityRecord->name, "%s", entity_name);

    newEntityRecord->entity = newEntity;

    Entities = g_list_append(Entities, newEntityRecord);

    printf("Index length: %i\n", g_list_length(Entities));

    return newEntity->id;
}

//Entity system setup
GList* Entities = NULL;
printf("Entity ID: %i\n", anne_entity_create("UNO", "PC", Entities));
printf("Entity ID: %i\n", anne_entity_create("DOS", "PC", Entities));
printf("Index length: %i\n", g_list_length(Entities));
```

The `g_list_length()` inside `anne_entity_create()` returns 1, while the same function executed outside returns 0. It's clear that the GList is being copied as it's passed to `anne_entity_create()`, but I'm at a loss for why - and passing it by *&reference* shouldn't be necessary, as (to my understanding) creating a GList with the `GList* Foo;` syntax results in a pointer anyway.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something I'm doing utterly, but I've been poking at this for hours.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a single pointer to your function, which means, you can modify what the pointer is pointing at, in this case, `NULL`, and you work with a local pointer (scoped to your function `anne_entity_create`) that points to `NULL`, then to that pointer you "attach" your list, which makes it only locally accessible.

So you need to use double indirection: pass a pointer to the head-of-list pointer to your function, and act on that, so you are changing the actual head of the list, instead of passing a copy of the address of the head of the list. Hope you understand, feel free to ask more.

```
GList *Entities = NULL;
anne_entity_create("UNO", "PC", &Entities) //Inside your function pass *Entities to append

// Creates a new entity and appends it to the global entity index.
// Returns ID of the newly created entity, not a pointer to it.
int anne_entity_create(char entity_name[], char entity_type[], GList **Entities) {

    ANNE_ENTITY *newEntity = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_ENTITY));
    ANNE_ENTITY_RECORD *newEntityRecord = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_ENTITY_RECORD));

    newEntity->id = anne_entity_get_next_id(*Entities);
    sprintf(newEntity->name, "%s", entity_name);
    sprintf(newEntityRecord->name, "%s", entity_name);

    newEntityRecord->entity = newEntity;

    *Entities = g_list_append(*Entities, newEntityRecord);

    printf("Index length: %i\n", g_list_length(*Entities));

    return newEntity->id;
}
```

Comment: `GList ** Entities; *Entities = NULL;` segfaults. Looking into it, but I only kind of understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: The principle of this answer is correct, but the code given will indeed segfault. I went ahead and edited it ;-)

Comment: Yep, I messed, it segfaults, because double pointer, is not initialised, as potato edited, you should pass the reference of the pointer, or allocate a double pointer, but solution provided by potato is better.

Comment: For the sake of progress, last night I rationalized jamming my list into a parent struct on the grounds that requirements could make additional data a good idea to pass around. I'm still going to copy out the pre-fix code from git and try your solution for the sake of self-enrichment, however. :)